# how to make a static binary of coreutils?

Tags: gcc, make, binary, coreutils

I'm trying to make a static binary of rm, so I tried compiling coreutils with

```
configure; make SHARED=0 CC='gcc -static'; make install
```

but I keep running into errors.

First make complains about c99 or gnu99, I solved that by adding -std=gnu99 to the CC value:

```
make SHARED=0 CC='gcc -static -std=gnu99'
```

After that it says:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__TMC_END__' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbeginT.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

I tried adding -fPIC like I added the -std option but to no avail.

Is it even possible to make static binaries of coreutils? (only interested in rm)
If so, how? (I have 0 experience with building linux binaries)

PS: I downloaded the coreutils source from the ubuntu site, trusty.(coreutils-8.21)

Comment: The `CC` variable is not the right place for compiler flags. You should put those in `CFLAGS`.

Comment: so while Sylvain's answer works, it could be improved by using CFLAGS instead of CC? Again, I know nothing about compiling C, I'm just a stupid Java programmer :)

Comment: If a statically linked `rm` is the endgoal, simply install [`busybox-static`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/busybox-static) or [`sash`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/sash).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per this [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.4/+bug/640734/comments/6) on bug #[640734](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.4/+bug/640734), there is a workaround that you may try:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
$ sudo cp crtbeginT.o crtbeginT.orig.o
$ sudo cp crtbeginS.o crtbeginT.o
```

Also, add `-fPIC` to the command above:

```
make SHARED=0 CFLAGS='-static -std=gnu99 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -fPIC'
```

Once you're done with the compilation just restore the original file like this:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
$ sudo cp crtbeginT.orig.o crtbeginT.o
$ sudo rm crtbeginT.orig.o
```

Comment: As mentioned in [my other comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530617/how-to-make-a-static-binary-of-coreutils?noredirect=1#comment724490_530617), this solution can be improved, if you replace `CC='gcc -static …'` by `CFLAGS='-static …'`. `CC` is meant to contain the C compiler to use, `CFLAGS` is dedicated to C compiler flags.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Good catch, thanks. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve a precompiled version with [static-get](https://github.com/minos-org/minos-static)

```
static-get -x coreutils
```

Comment: strangely this will download a 32bit x86 coreutils, so it won't work on 64bit systems =/ is there some way to download a 64bit x86-64 coreutils with static-get ?